# Access violation reading from random access file in c++

Tags: c++, file, random, binary, access-violation

This part of the program that I'm making is supposed to print out all the records stored in a random access binary file.  Every time I run it, it prints out all of the records and then throws an access violation exception:

```
void readFile()
{
    ifstream inFile("hardware.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if(!inFile)
    {
        cerr<<"File could not be opened."<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout<<left<<setw(10)<<"Account"<<setw(16)
            <<"Name"<<setw(11)<<"Quantity"<<left<<setw(10)<<"Price"<<endl;

    Hardware File;

    inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&File), sizeof(Hardware));

    while(inFile && !inFile.eof())
    {
        if(File.getAccountNumber() != 0)
            outputLine(cout, File);

        inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&File), sizeof(Hardware));
    }
}
```

To clarify, "Hardware" is a class stored in Hardware.h.

hardware.h

```
#ifndef HARDWARE_H
#define HARDWARE_H

#include <string>
using std::string;

class Hardware
{
public:
Hardware (int = 0, string = "", int = 0, double = 0);

void setAccountNumber(int);
int getAccountNumber() const;

void setName(string);
string getName() const;

void setAmount(int);
int getAmount() const;

void setPrice(double);
double getPrice() const;
private:
int accountNumber;
string name;
int amount;
double price;
};

#endif
```

hardware.cpp

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

#include "hardware.h"

Hardware::Hardware(int accountNumberValue, string nameValue, int amountValue, double priceValue)                            

{
setAccountNumber(accountNumberValue);
setName(nameValue);
setAmount(amountValue);
setPrice(priceValue);
}

void Hardware::setAccountNumber(int accountValue)
{
accountNumber = accountValue;
}

int Hardware::getAccountNumber() const
{
return accountNumber;
}

void Hardware::setName(string nameValue)
{
name = nameValue;
}

string Hardware::getName() const
{
return name;
}

void Hardware::setAmount(int amountValue)
{
amount = amountValue;
}

int Hardware::getAmount() const
{
return amount;
}

void Hardware::setPrice(double priceValue)
{
price = priceValue;
}

double Hardware::getPrice() const
{
return price;
}
```

Comment: How are `inFile` and `File` (and `Hardware`) defined? Right now your code doesn't look like it makes much sense at all -- even at very best what you have is really ugly. The access violation sounds like you're probably overrunning a buffer (quite possibly when you read into `File` as if it were an array of char). Definitely too many "WTF"s for only four lines of code (oh, and your loop control is clearly wrong too).

Comment: I'll put up the rest of the function, it should clarify it (although, there may still be many "wtf"s).

Comment: Reading the raw bytes of a C++ object from a file is an extremely bad idea - it almost always is undefined behavior and causes crashes.  How did you define `Hardware`?

Comment: You can't really read (or write) a `std::string` like that. You should read up on [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Which line is the problem?  Also, it's reading (and writing) fine, except that it seems to go over the boundary of the file.  All the data is printed out though...

Answer (score 1):

As Joachim said, you can't read into a `std::string` like that.

It isn't a value type; internally it will hold a pointer to a memory region containing its text. If you read in a random blob of binary from a file, that string pointer could be pointing anywhere; dereferencing it (say, by getting or setting the value of 'name') is likely to throw an access violation or segfault or whatever.

I'd add a couple of new methods, like this (not guaranteed to compile or work!):

```
void Hardware::Serialise(std::ostream& stream) const
{
  stream << accountName << "\n" << accountNumber << "\n" << accountValue << std::endl;
}
void Hardware::Deserialise(std::istream& stream)
{
  char[1024] buffer;
  stream.readsome(buffer, 1024);
  accountName = buffer;
  buffer >> accountNumber >> accountValue;
}
```

Knowledge of the internal structure of the object is pretty key to (de)serialising it correctly. Handling failure conditions, inter-record delimiters and using a stringstream instead of a fxied-size buffer to read the name into are left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Simple example added to the answer.